# REACT - cannot invoke onClick()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs

I have this custom component to render an icon **Notify**:

```js
<div className="nav-item__wide-screen">
    <Notify 
    onClick={() => markAsRead()}  // <== here
    Icon={NotificationsOutlineIcon} 
    notify={unreadNum} 
  />
</div>
```

And the markAsRead method is :

```js
const markAsRead = async () => {    
    console.log('REQUESTING FOR READ NOTIFICATIONS')
    // await makeRequest();
  };
```

And the Notify component is :

```js
 const Notify = ({ Icon, notify, size }) => {
  let fontSize = size || 20;
  return (
    <div className="notify">
      <Icon className="notify__icon" style={{ fontSize }} />
      {
        notify && <span className="notify__number">{notify}</span>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have never faced this issue, its crazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing an `onClick` prop to the component, but the component doesn't use or reference such a prop. Change your Notify to:

```
 const Notify = ({ Icon, notify, size, onClick }) => {
  let fontSize = size || 20;
  return (
    <div onClick={onClick} className="notify">
      <Icon className="notify__icon" style={{ fontSize }} />
      {
        notify && <span className="notify__number">{notify}</span>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't realize that. Thanks alot.I started doubting myself for a moment there.